# SQL-запрос, выводящий max(count(...)) и другие поля таблицы, соответствующие max-параметру

Tags: запрос, sql

Имеются следующие таблицы:

```
Person(поля Nom и др.) - информация о людях,
Profit(поля ID, Source, Moneys) - источники дохода,
Have_d(поля Nom, ID и др.) - связь между людьми и их доходами.
```

Каждый человек может иметь несколько источников дохода.
Необходимо вывести всю информацию о самом популярном источнике дохода. То есть необходимо подсчитать количество включений всех видов доходов, выбрать максимальное и вывести полученное число вместе со всеми полями таблицы `Profit`, соответствующими полученному максимуму.

Я смогла вывести максимальное число, но не получается составить запрос на вывод строки из `Profit`, ему соответствующей.

```
    select max(expr1)
    from (select count(nom) as expr1
        from profit, have_d, person
        where profit.id = have_d.id 
        and have_d.nom = person.nom
        group by source)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема известная. :-)
[Здесь](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_aggregate_function_to_aggregate_function/page2.html) найдете решение.

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо за ссылку. Теперь в нужном виде запрос выглядит так:

```
select top 1 t1.*
from (select profit.source,count(*) as expr1
    from profit, have_d
    where profit.id = have_d.id 
    group by profit.source) as t1 
order by expr1 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.*
from (select profit.*,count(*) as expr1
    from profit, have_d
    where profit.id = have_d.id 
    group by profit.id
    order by expr1 desc) as t1 
limit 1
```

Я уверен есть решение лучше (скажем без limit). Таблица `person` не нужна.